# Magento 2: custom product import taking long time

Tags: magento2, cron, import-products, time

We had a magento 2.3.0 multi-website shop and we use custom product import for shops.
We use CLI script as a config for each shops and execute import with a common custom module handing few checkings.
We read the a pre-defined column file and import to corresponding product attributes.
Each shops crons are set on different timing(for example, for shop X we have "php importX.php" where we define basic configuration like website id, code,sku prefix etc).
Now issue we have is some shops having around 3500 rows in the file and it's taking more than 7 hours to complete.
Any advice on this really appreciated.

Comment: Well if I were to solve the problem, first of all I would try to find which process takes most time for, updating 3k products should not take 7hours long, unless you are fetching data for the products from an external source and you need to check ea product separately.
To better answer your question, we would need to know what does take most time in the process, is it saving products or retrieving products data. Saving products can be handled by queuing saves on DB, as for the 2nd one it depends on various things

Comment: Thank you @GosuPrzmak for the reply. We have a log after each product save which indicates, each product takes 4-5 seconds. We had staging environment in different server and it takes 2-3 seconds for the same. We have some custom checking in each product save. We will analyse time on each step and get back.

Comment: Do you product has tier price? Maybe it's related to this issue? https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28225

Comment: @Jimmy Thank you for the reply. No tier prices in this case.